# Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function. Prove that $f(z)=cz^n$ for some constant $c$ and positive integer $n$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function satisfying the following conditions:

1. $$f(0)=0$$
2. for each $M \gt 0$ the set $$\{z \mid \lvert f(z)\rvert \lt M\}$$ is connected.

   Prove that $f(z)=cz^n$ for some constant $c$ and positive integer $n$.

My try:

Since $f(0)=0$ and the zeroes of $f$ are isolated (as $f$ is non-constant), there exists a $r \gt 0$ such that $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z$ satisfying $\{\lvert z\rvert \le r\}$ except $z=0$. (Call the set $C = \{z \mid \lvert z\rvert \le r\}$).

Now $f(z)$ attains its minimum (say $\delta \gt 0$) on the circle $\{\lvert z\rvert = r\}$. Then $S = \{z \mid \lvert f(z)\rvert \lt \delta\}$ intersects $C$, and since $S$ is connected, it has to lie completely inside $C$. Moreover there is no zero of $f$ other than $0$. (Had it been so, it would have belonged to the set $S$ and hence would have lied completely inside $C$ which would have violated the choice of $r$.

Somehow this should imply that $f$ is bounded away from the origin. I try to proceed by contradiction: Suppose not. Then for every $M \gt 0$ there exists a $z_0$ such that $\lvert z_0\rvert \gt r$ for any $r \gt 0$ we have $\lvert f(z_0)\rvert \gt M$. I go nowhere from here.

If I can conclude that $f$ is bounded away from origin, then I would be through for then $f$ would have a pole at $\infty$ and hence $f(z) = z^n$.

How do I conclude that??

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already shown that

$$S = \{ z : \lvert f(z)\rvert < \delta\} \subset C = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r\}.$$

From that, it follows directly that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \geqslant \delta$ for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert > r$, and that shows that $f$ cannot have an essential singularity at $\infty$, so it is a polynomial. As a non-constant polynomial with only a single zero at $0$ (the zero can of course have multiplicity greater than $1$), it is of the form

$$f(z) = cz^n$$

for some $c\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$.